# selecting n row from mysql optimized way

Tags: mysql

i am using below query to select 10 rows from mysql but it causes heavy load on server as it searches for 4000000 rows.

```
   explain SELECT * FROM `tableA` where status = '0' and id < '9600000' order by id desc  LIMIT 10
```

if i can use > along with < then the result set is quite low and query is fast but i dont know the other side of data value so i cant use >.talking about below query which is optimized but i cant use as i dont know next no

```
  explain SELECT * FROM `tableA` where status = '0' and id >'9500000'and id < '9600000' order by id desc  LIMIT 10
```

but 9500000 changes and i dont know how to predict this value to optimize my query.
Any thought will be great
EXPLAIN OUTPUT

```
     id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
     1  SIMPLE  tableA range    PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   NULL    3890786     Using where
```

Comment: Pls share the result of explain and the list of indexes with us. I do not really understand this predict bit. Do you know the lower limit when you execute the query or not?

Comment: i dont know lower limit and status and id are indexed

Comment: Status and id are indexed **how**? Pls be specific! And pls share the explain with us, so we can see how the indexes are used!

Comment: updated output in question